# moment.js for start and displayiing a counter

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I am starting to use moment.js and want to start a timer from a given timestamp.

So in this div I want tp display a counter starting from a timestamp 1390310209.967228 and start counting realtime hours, minutes and seconds from that timestamp.

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var startTimestamp;
function startTimer(myStartTimestamp)
{
    startTimestamp = parseInt(myStartTimestamp);
    setInterval(function() {
        startTimestamp++;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 
            moment.unix(startTimestamp).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    }, 1000);
}

</script>

<body onload="startTimer(1390310209.967228)">
    <div id="timer"></div>
</body>
```

Outputs live counter from given starting unix timestamp:

```
Tuesday, January 21st 2014, 1:17:50 pm
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NjK7H/